# Trying to pivot a table using Apache spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataset in csv file, Can anyone tell me how to pivot the dataset on a particular column using Apache spark java program.

Sample data:

```
id | name | city
1    john   Newyork
2    smith  LA
3    mike   Boston
```

I am trying to do pivot on city column

Outcome should be:

```
id | name | Newyork | LA | Boston
1   john      1        0     0
2   smith     0        1     0
3   mike      0        0     1
```

..Thanks and in advance

Comment: I think you need to reformat your example data

Answer (score 1):

you could use mllib sparse and dense vectors:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html

you could create a look up table one for the names and another for the city with RDD.zipWithUniqueId, which gives a Long convert it to a double, and use the doubles to feed into the dense vector.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Df.groupby(col("id")).pivot("city")